# iptables -j MASQUERADE for a specific network interface: after connecting to a VPN and changing the default route, connection in the peer is lost

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, ip-forwarding, network-namespace

I use to forward traffic from my wireless card to network namespaces.

I create the network namespace, virtual ethernet interfaces and all the rest:

```
ip netns add nsx
ip link add vethx type veth peer name peerx netns nsx
ip link set vethx up
ip address add 10.0.0.1/24 dev vethx
ip netns exec nsx ip link set peerx up
ip netns exec nsx ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev peerx
ip netns exec nsx ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev peerx
mkdir -p /etc/netns/nsx
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > /etc/netns/nsx/resolv.conf
```

And I enable forwarding in the interfaces used and enable MASQUERADE in NAT table:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.forwarding=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vethx.forwarding=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

It works, but when I connect to a VPN in the host the connections inside the network namespace are stopped.

This is my route table after connecting to a VPN:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.240.30.118 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.4 metric 100 
10.240.30.118 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.240.30.117 
127.0.0.1 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.240.30.118 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.4 metric 100
```

What must be done to make all the traffic of network namespace flows through the wireless interface when connecting to a VPN?